# Is it possible to set path permissions from the svn command- line?

Tags: svn, command-line, permissions

A user recently asked me if it is possible to protect a branch from a script.  While I know how to set path based permissions from the server side my searches for this answer have eluded me.  Is it possible to modify the permissions on a branch from the svn command-line?

Comment: What is wrong in using the path based permissions as explained [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz)? It is easy to setup, and restricts the change of permissions to administrators. You could set it up that some people have the right to change permissions by changing the file and committing it to subversion. If you are interested, I could give the idea as an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Subversion doesn't include permissions as part of the repository, but you can run a commit [hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) script to reject commits to areas of the repository based on whatever criteria you want.

Comment: Depending on how you contact your repository you can apply permissions. (Supported for svn://, http:// and https://. Not for file:/// but in that case you have the filesystem rights to destroy the repository anyway). See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/